How to get colored prediction output in multiclass UNET segmentation
i have the same data and annotation just like show in the provided link,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019869/u-net-how-to-improve-accuracy-of-multiclass-segmentation/78453876#78453876
query : why i didnot get the colored output prediction, i have the same task which he did in the provided link (please go through), i.e i get one same gray color of all segmented objects
How to get per-class probability etc you can provide me the prediction code also. Response would be appreciated, Thank you
